# (Tensorflow 2.0) Keras Dataframe cannot detect the validation images

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, image-classification

I tried to use **keras.ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe**, but it cannot detect the validation images and I get this

Found 162770 validated image filenames.

Found 0 validated image filenames.

Can anyone help me please

My code is here:

```
traindf=pd.read_csv('E:/color.csv')
columns=["Black", "White", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Brown", "Yellow"]

datagen=ImageDataGenerator()    
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=traindf,
directory="E:/Experimental_Data",
x_col="image_id",
y_col=columns,
subset="training",
batch_size=32,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
class_mode="raw",
target_size=(178,218))

test_datagen=ImageDataGenerator()
valid_generator=test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=traindf,
directory="E:/Experimental_Data",
x_col="image_id",
y_col=columns,
subset="validation",
batch_size=32,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
class_mode="raw",
target_size=(178,218))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you getting 0 validated images as output than what is 162770 number indicates? elaborate the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thank You for responding
The dataframe loads all the training images that are (162770), but cannot load the validation images and return (0), as a result the model cannot calculate the loss function as shown in the image.

Comment: It is hard find root cause, could you please share complete code along with sample data to investigate the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i guess this problem arises because the **x_col** and **y_col** do not have the same dimension. You have to prepare a script so that based on some characteristic(depends on your data) all the **x_col** components has a respective **y_col** component. All the colors that you have included in **columns** as list has to be mapped to each of the **x_col** in that script. Then you can use that mapping to define your **y_col**, the dimensions of **x_col** and **y_col** will match. The rest will work fine after that. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you have to set a validation fraction in your call to ImageDataGenerator, for example:

```
datagen=ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=0.2)
```

I just had this same problem, and it is now fixed.
Found answer in https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#flowfromdataframe-method:

> subset: Subset of data ("training" or "validation") if validation_split is set in ImageDataGenerator.